# Place of arrival when travelling to UK via connecting flights?

Tags: uk

I'm travelling to Edinburgh for college tomorrow from India. While completing the mandatory **passenger locator form**, I am asked the following questions:

1. Where will you arrive in the UK?
2. What is your flight number?
3. What is the time of arrival?

Now it's not a direct flight. I'd be going from Kolkata (India) to Delhi (India); then Delhi to Heathrow; then finally Heathrow to Edinburgh. All of them are British Airways flights, booked under the same PNR but with different flight numbers. I am confused about what to put as answers to the above questions: for 1, should I write Heathrow, or Edinburgh? For 2, which flight do they want to know? Delhi to London or London to Edinburgh? And for 3, should I mention the time I arrive at London or the time I arrive at Edinburgh? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will be clearing UK immigration in Heathrow, so I would use that as "arrival at the UK border.".

The flight from London to Edinburgh is only a domestic flight with no controls or documentation requirements (other than your ID and boarding pass).

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only does this answer my question but also explains the reasoning behind it! Makes complete sense.